# What spacetimes satisfy this identity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

1. What spacetimes satisfy  $R^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu} =\alpha R^2$, where $R = g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci scalar, and $\alpha$ is some constant?
2. A follow-up question: in what spacetimes does $R^{\mu\nu\sigma\rho} R_{\mu\nu\sigma\rho} =\beta R^2$, for some constant $\beta$?

Comment: How many dimensions are we working in? Or is it a general question in any dimension. For example, in two dimensions, the above statements are true for any metric. One possible solution for higher dimensional space-times are the maximally symmetric ones. (Flat, dS, and AdS)

Comment: Ideally 3+1 dimensions, but anything would be useful.

Comment: $\alpha R^2=\alpha R^\mu_{\;\;\mu} R^\nu_{\;\;\nu}=\alpha g_{\lambda\mu}g^{\rho\nu}R^{\mu\lambda}R_{\nu\rho}$
Hence, we have equality when $\alpha g_{\lambda\mu}g^{\rho\nu}=\delta_\lambda^\nu\delta^\rho_\mu$.

Comment: An example more general than maximally symmetric space would be Einstein spaces $R_{\mu\nu}=\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$. In particular Ricci-flat space-times correspond to $\alpha=0$.

Comment: can I ask the physical relevance of this identity?

Comment: I'm interested in modified gravity lagrangians with both $R^2$ and $R^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$

Answer (score 7):

I can give you some particular solutions, but not the most general solution.

1. Any metric in 2 dimensions satisfies
   $$
   R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = \frac{R}{2} \left( g_{\mu\alpha} g_{\nu\beta} - g_{\mu\beta} g_{\nu\alpha} \right) \implies R_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} R
   $$
   This implies
   $$
   R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = R^2,~~ R_{\mu\nu} R^{\mu\nu} = \frac{R^2}{2}
   $$
   Thus, in two dimensions, $\alpha = 1/2$ and $\beta = 1$.
2. Maximally symmetric space-times in $d$ dimensions that satisfy
   $$
   R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = \frac{R}{d(d-1)} \left( g_{\mu\alpha} g_{\nu\beta} - g_{\mu\beta} g_{\nu\alpha} \right) \implies R_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{d} g_{\mu\nu} R
   $$
   From this, we get
   $$
   R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = \frac{2 R^2}{d(d-1)},~~ R_{\mu\nu} R^{\mu\nu} = \frac{R^2}{d}
   $$
   Thus, for maximally symmetric space-times in $d$-dimensions, $\alpha = \frac{1}{d}$ and $\beta = \frac{2}{d(d-1)}$.